# Enviar ALT+B comunicación COM C#

Tags: c#, serialport

Estoy intentando establecer una comunicación por el puerto serial de la computadora y requiero enviar a mi dispositivo la combinación de teclas <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> para que pueda responder, el problema es que no puedo encontrar la manera de enviar <kbd>ALT</kbd>.

```
    private void connectionFlashChb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if(connectionFlashChb.Checked == true)
        {
            if (port.IsOpen)
            {
                port.Write(Keys.Alt.ToString()+Keys.B.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

En esta clase estoy escribiendo por el puerto serie la combinación de teclas , pero parece no funcionar puesto que el dispositivo no responde, intente hacerlo de forma manual por una Hyperterminal y funciona correctamente. 
Alguien sabe como mandar la secuencia de <kbd>ALT</kbd> + el carácter <kbd>b</kbd> ?

Todo lo estoy realizando en C#

Comment: Ni idea como se hace, pero probaste mandarlo como ascii?

Comment: Si , y no funciona.
Estoy utilizando una terminal llamada TERATERM , donde se le envia ese comando y encontre este documento https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/en/usage/keyboard.html

Comment: Prueba con `serialPort1.Write(new byte[]{ 72 },0,1);` para enviar Alt+b a ver si funciona...

Comment: ¿De dónde sacaste el _alt+b_? Esa secuencia, hasta donde recuerdo, no tiene un equivalente estándar, así que debe ser la forma de representar, en esa _cosa_ un carácter no imprimible (usualmente ASCII < 32) o carácter extendido (ASCII > 127). Busca en la documentación de dónde la sacaste, a ver a que ASCII, o secuencia de carácteres corresponde ese _alt+b_ y envía ese caracter o esa secuencia.